# how to raise variable to a power without using "^"?

Tags: matlab

Basically, the only way I know to raise a variable to a power is by writing it like this (a^b). I've been asked to do the same thing without using "^" operator

Comment: Does matlab have a pow() function?

Comment: yes! [power(a,b)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/power.html)

Comment: What have you tried? If `b` is always a non-negative integer, you can do it with successive multiplications.

Answer (score -1):

How about you write a function that defined "to the power of"? A simple loop will suffice. Then you can call your own function instead of using the "^" operator.

Comment: do you mean write your own version of [`power`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/power.html)?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean. Think about how you would do it by hand then just translate it into code.